# Loop does not break

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, user-input

Here is my piece of code and for some reason it continues even if I enter AM or PM correct

```
while True:
    user_in = input('Please enter the time in the following 12Hour format HH:MM AM|PM : ')

    time_in = user_in.split()
    time_input = time_in[0].split(':')
    latin_input = time_in[1]

    if (latin_input != 'AM' and latin_input != 'PM'):
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: hmmm seems to work fine for me. could you please provide what input you are using?

Comment: try `'AM' not in latin_input and 'PM' not in latin_input`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are having this issue. I tried your code and it works.

I would recommend first before you split and start to do indexing check if there are time and latin_input, so when you use indexing it's not breaking your code. Validation first and then processing. Something like this:

```
while True:
    user_in = input('Please enter the time in the following 12Hour format HH:MM AM|PM : ')

    if len(user_in.split()) != 2 and not user_in.endswith(('AM', 'PM')):
        continue

    time_in, latin_input = user_in.split()

    break
```